# Docker "/desktop/vms/" using more storage than the Disk image size defined

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I've defined my Disk image size to a mere 16GB, and Docker is allocating 32GB as of this moment. I have had the issue before, when the limit was the default 64GB, Docker was using almost 80GB.
I reduced this limit, accepting the warning that my images would be deleted, but nothing changed, it indicated that the size was 16GB but was still using 64GB.
I ran `docker prune`, deleted all my images, containers and volumes and the size didn't reduce by a single Gigabyte.

In the end I decided to reinstall docker altogether, but even after the removal I had to manually delete the content from the path (`/home/victor/.docker/desktop/vms/0/data`)

My question is: How can Docker bypass its own Disk image size limit? Could it be allocating the disk space and then not using it? Or could it be missing some permission from the os to delete the actual files and just indicating that it has deleted but hasn't?

I'll have to reinstall Docker a second time after just two weeks, loosing all my volumes data and having to pull all the images yet again.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit

[Disk Usage Analyzer - analysis of the path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLZ8y.png)

[Docker Desktop - Resources tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp6Qx.png)

Comment: I just noticed this too.  I've tried deleting the Docker.raw after setting the virtual disk limit down to 8 gb but the size still gets set to 32GB.  I noticed that if I size up to 40GB, the file will get recreated to 42GB on disk, but then if I try to shrink it down to 8GB, the file get recreated still at 32GB.

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem. Set virtual disk limit to 16GB and defaults to 32GB.

Comment: I actually had to downgrade from Ubuntu 22 to Ubuntu 20 in order to get to respect the size limit. It was becoming unmanageable as I couldn't fix it.