# Is Docker.raw necessary or can be erased?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

## Problem

I decided to learn *Docker* and followed the official [installation guide](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/), specifically [for ubuntu](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/).

After downloading some images and making some containers to test how everything works, using *CLI* and *Desktop App*, found that my system ran out of memory.

Find out that a file called ***"Docker.raw"*** was created and consume 8.4GB of memory. The thing it's that I don't know for what is that file.

[image: Disk Analysis Image]

I have my *disk space limit* setted to 8GB, so don't understand the overlow:

[image: Docker Configuration Image]

Find out 2 things:

1. It's a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73394952/docker-desktop-vms-using-more-storage-than-the-disk-image-size-defined), [on multiple systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device).
2. Everybody recommend this command:

```bash
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

## What I tried

I tried executing the command above, since it's the general answer for this problem, but doesn't work at all:

```bash
$ docker system prune -a --volumes
WARNING! This will remove:
  - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all volumes not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

Doesn't free any space.

## What I'm searching, if anyone can help

1. A confirmation that I can erase *Docker.raw* or not, since I don't find a clear answer if it's necesary for docker to work.
2. An alternative to clear the space, because the common solution didn't work.

## Aditional Information

1. OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
2. Docker: vr. 24.0.1, build 6802122
3. Docker Compose: vr. 2.17.3
4. Disk Size: 128GB
5. Yes, my disk it's filled with many things and always fight with space, that's why I have problems with this new *disk-space-eater* and want to erase it.

Comment: Did you work this out? I'm hitting the same issue.

Comment: @Dan did any of you?

Comment: @LeeSkies - Sorry, I can't remember. I don't seem to have that file now though. I would have reset my Docker installation many times since my initial comment above.

Comment: @Dan figured, I ended up deleting it anyway and it doesn't seem to have an impact